# Is it possible that $P^t A P$ is digonal, but $P^{-1} A P$ isn't?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm searching for a matrix $A$ $\in$ $M(n,\mathbb{R})$, such that there exists $P$ $\in$ $Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$ satisfying the following condition:
$$P^t A P\  \mbox{ is diagonal, but  }  P^{-1}AP \ \mbox{isn't diagonal}. $$

Is it possible exists such matrices?

Can anyone help me?

---

Counter-example using user357980's suggestion

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
3/2& -1/2 \\
-1/2 &1/2
\end{bmatrix}, \quad P= \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}.  $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: Consider $n = 2$ (simplest case). Take a diagonalizable matrix $A$ that does not look diagonal and let $P$ be a matrix of eigenvectors so that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal. I would be surprised if $P^T A P$ was also diagonal.

Comment: I'm looking to the conversely, I'm supposing that $P^t A P$ is diagonal, and not that $P^{-1}A P$ is diagonal.

Comment: Ok, well start with a diagonal matrix $D (= P^t A P)$ and find an invertible matrix $P$ that looks rather non-diagonal. Then compute $P^{-1}AP = P^{-1}(P^t)^{-1}D$ and I would expect it to be not diagonal.

Comment: Your suggestion worked!!!